# Android possible to join Contacts Table with own table?

Tags: android

Is it possible to use a query to JOIN the default Contacts table with your own table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not through SQL or `ContentResolver`. You can use techniques like [`CursorJoiner`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorJoiner.html) to create a `Cursor` that joins two other `Cursors`.